# Point does not name a type

Tags: c++

```
Point* createPoint(double x, double y, double z)
{

Point* point = new Point;
point->x = x;
point->y = y;
point->z = z;


return point;
}
```

So MinGW is telling me that 'Point does not name a type' and I'm not really sure how or why. PS: I know these are bad variable names. xD

**EDIT** This is how our teacher wants us to format the program. I have the struct initially right above this. We just started working with structs so I'm mainly confused on syntax and what not.

```
struct Point
{
double x;
double y;
double z;
};
```

Comment: How and where do you declare the Point class/struct? And I don't think those are bad variable names.

Comment: No need for pointers here.

Comment: Point does not name a type because you either have declared it as a simple struct (without a typedef) like `typedef struct sPoint { double x, y, z;} Point` or you haven't declared it at all.

Comment: @FlaviusAnton, the question is tagged C++, so the typedef would be unnecessary.

Comment: @CarlNorum, yes you're right. Didn't notice the tag for C++.

Comment: Unfortunately your teacher is teaching you bad habits. I can't see any reason to dynamically allocate your point in this way. You can just return it from the function by value, and a constructor should be used instead of this function.

Comment: @NeilKirk This is what you find when Java professors teach C++

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with g++ and not gcc?

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you try a brand new file with just the struct definition and then the function definition?

Answer (score 0):

How would the compiler know that `Point` contains three variables called `x`, `y`, and `z`? How would it know what type they are? You have to tell the compiler these things.